# Will I save bandwidth with this code (200 bytes), or is the entire page opened? file_get_contents('http://example.com', false, null, 0, 200);

Tags: php, file-get-contents, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags, meta

The following line of code grabs the first 200 characters from the webpage and then echos them.

Does this mean that my server, and the remote server only send 200 bytes of data to each other? In other words, if I run this code 4 times, is only 800 bytes of data transferred?

Or, if the page at example.com is 250kb, and I run this code 4 times, will 1MB of data be transferred?

I'm trying to make sure that I don't overload servers by sending too many requests and only need the first few hundred characters to get the meta tags and og tags.

```
$s = file_get_contents('http://example.com', false, null, 0, 200);
echo $s;
```

**Will this code transfer 200 bytes of data between servers, or will it transfer the amount of data of the ENTIRE page of example.com, say 250kb for instance?**

---

I searched the web, read the php.net manual and can't find a clear cut answer to this question. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why did you add the [tag:opengraph] tag?

Comment: Because I'm actually trying to fetch an og:image, and I thought this could be helpful to people who are working in opengraph as it can potentially save them bandwidth by using the null protocol. And I used the opengraph tag because it's likely people searching in that tag would know about this. Other opengraph DOM and file_get_content codes seem to request the entire page, which is a lot of bandwidth on servers. And I'd like to save bandwidth if possible.